# How to give different titles to matplotlib plots when parsing from csv?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, matplotlib

I wrote the python code below to read a CSV and generate multiple plots at once. However, I can't figure out how to give matplotlib the Location value from the csv I'm reading as I would like to have each plot labeled with the location value that I am aggregating on. Please see the code and screenshot below.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab import files
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

myfile = files.upload()
df = pd.read_csv('Electricity.csv')
df2 = df.groupby(['Location'], as_index=False)
print(df2)
df2.plot(x='Period', y = 'score', ylim=(0,11))#IDK about ylim being necessary 
plt.title('Location', color='black')
plt._show()
```

[Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKgji.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Get the axes retured by `df2.plot`, and since you're grouping by `Location` you'll have something similar to:

```py
   Location                                 NaN
0 Location1  AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
1 Location2  AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
2 Location3  AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
```

Use the `apply` function with `axis=1` to get current axis *and* the location. With the axis object use `set_title` using the `Location` for each plot.

```py
...
df2.apply(print)
ax = df2.plot(x='Period', y='score', ylim=(0, 11))

ax.apply(lambda x: x[1].set_title(x['Location']), axis=1)

plt.show()
```